# Images do not load | Ruby on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in the process of learning Ruby on Rails and have begun working on my first project. My aim is to create a navbar that consists of two images: a full-screen background image spanning the navbar's entire length, and a logo image positioned at the center. However, I'm facing an issue where the images aren't loading properly, and instead, I'm seeing icons displaying the file names. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this problem?

[image]

_header.html.erb file:

```
<nav class="navbar_bg">
    <img src="<%= asset_path('navbar_bg.png') %>" class="navbar-bg" alt="Navbar Bg">
    <div class="navbar_logo">
        <img src="<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>" class="navbar-logo" alt="Navbar logo">
    </div>
</nav>
```

application.css:

```
 .navbar {
    position: relative;
}
.navbar-bg {
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 50px;
    /* Adjust the size as needed */
}
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>RD</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>

  <%= render 'home/header' %>
  <div class="container"> 
    <br/>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When print out `<%= asset_path('navbar_bg.png') %>`  onto the page .. What does it look like?  Are you able to hit it directly in your browser? by appending `127.0.0.1:3000/<output>` ?

Comment: Are there any errors in your web console?

Comment: If it doesn't look right . Look into the settings in `config.assets.prefix` and set your assets location appropriately.

Comment: Where do you keep that images? Did you try to replace `asset_path` with `image_path`?

Comment: @mechnicov yes, doesn't work. I got this error: "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/%3C%=%20image_path('logo.png')%20%%3E"):"

Comment: Hm, looks like you made some mistake in the erb brackets or something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it was a stupid oversight - the file name was _header.html instead of _header.html.erb

Anyway, thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `<image...` with:

```
<%= image_tag('navbar_bg.png', class: "navbar-bg", alt: "Navbar Bg") %>
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Comment: I've tried this, but all I got was the literal text of the code displayed in the place of previous image icons.

Comment: OK, that description is less than helpful. But if you edit your comment to show the actual HTML generated by my code I can help troubleshoot it. If it's just showing raw HTML in the view then you might need a `raw()` in there.